# C++ Window draggable by a bitmap

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing a custom window border in c++, well i guess that's what it is.  I don't know if i'm doing this the correct way or not, but i would appreciate knowing how to make a draggable window by a bitmap.

there is a bitmap bar i made in photoshop and added to the client area, and i want to be able to drag it just by the bitmap.  Currently you can drag it by anywhere in the client area using this code:

```
case WM_NCHITTEST: {
    LRESULT hit = DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    if(hit == HTCLIENT) hit = HTCAPTION;
    return hit;
    }
    break;
```

and I drew the bitmap using this code in the paint section:

```
DrawBitmap(hdc,"header-bar-1.bmp", 2, 4);
```

and it looks like so:

[image: window]

You can see the bar at the top, which is what i want to be able to drag it by.

Comment: You get the mouse position in this message, the lParam argument.  Just check if it matches the bitmap position.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but something similar should work:

1. Declare a Boolean value called e.g. `isDragging` and set it to false.
2. In the handler of `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, if `isDragging` is false and the mouse is over the bitmap bar (use `PtInRect`), set `isDragging` to true, and confine the cursor into the rectangle of the bitmap by calling `ClipCursor`. Save the position of the cursor relative to the window upper-left corner.
3. In the handler of `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, if `isDragging` is true, move the window (call `MoveWindow` or `SetWindowPos`) in order to restore its position relative to the cursor.
4. In the handler of `WM_LBUTTONUP`, if `isDragging` is true, set it to false, and release the cursor by calling `ClipCursor` appropriately.

(Always take the difference between client coordinates and screen coordinates into account.)